# Why there is "not a function" error if calling a function before function declaration with es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using older syntax

Prints "this is myfunc1"

```
myfunc1();

function myfunc1() {
console.log("this is myfunc1");
}
```

Using es6 syntax
This gives error "myfunc2 is not a function"

```
myfunc2();

var myfunc2 = () => {
  console.log("this is myfunc2");
}
```

Comment: Is it something related to hoisting?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6 syntax. You are using a variable before it is instantiated. You would have the same result doing `var myfunc1 = function() {...}`

Comment: @Nicolas — With `let` the error would be "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myfunc2' before initialization" because `var` is hoisted but `let` is not so you'd hit the temporal dead zone.

Comment: why it gives "not a function" rather than undefined?

Comment: if i print a variable before it is declared, Js prints undefined.

Comment: @AnkulSinghRajput — That's a standard error from trying to treat any value that isn't a function as a function.

Comment: @AnkulSinghRajput because you are using the variable rather than printing it. `console.log(myfunc1)` would give `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations are hoisted.

Variable declarations using `var` keyword are also hoisted (meaning the Javascript engine "knows" the variable has been declared) **but**, because **assignments are not hoisted**, the variable will contain `undefined` until the line of code that does the assignment is executed.

---

Do not consider this "old" and "new" syntax.

Function declarations, function expressions, and arrow functions all have **[different behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)**. While arrow functions were introduced to the language more recently, they are **not** a replacement for function declarations or function expressions.